# Why th first link in Sankey diagram it is not shown in R?

Tags: r, hyperlink, sankey-diagram

My Sankey diagram shows all the elements and the colors that I want but it doesn't shows the link between the first node and the second one.
I tried to modify the source and the target in order to match but it doesn't work.
Did you had the same problem ? How you resolved it?

Many thanks
Nicoleta

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately, we won't be able to help without a so-called reprex. That means, we need the smallest possible piece of your code and at least as much of your data that is necessary to reproduce the problem. You can export the data with `dput()` or `dput(head())`if the data are large and add it to your question. Furthermore, which package are you using for the Sankey diagram? That information would be invaluable, too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that I was using an old version of R that didn't supported the package.